# BitmapImage sourceStream is null in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, stream

I'm using the following function to load a bitmap image

```
private BitmapImage fileNameBitMap(string filePath)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) && File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;


            bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(filePath);
            bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;

            bitmap.EndInit();
            image = bitmap;
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I debug the bitmap.SourceStream I find it equal to null, also I find a FormatNotSupportedException is thrown.
I need to store the BitmapImage in a stream in a process of converting it to a byte[].

Comment: I guess you mean `BitmapImage.StreamSource`. Of course it's `null`, because you haven't set it. You have set `UriSource` instead. Why don't you simply read the `byte[]` from the image file (e.g. by `File.ReadAllBytes)`?

Comment: I did that :) it is a nice solution , thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply read the content of the image file into a `byte[]`:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```